# Время отсчёта PHP

Tags: php, mysql, дата, время

Здравствуйте. И так, назрел вопрос. Как же всё таки нормально оформить таймер обратного отсчёта времени? Суть такова, человек получает что то на час. Это считывается к примеру функцией `time();`. Добавим туда наш час `time() + 60 * 60;`
Получается что есть две переменные. То что нужно. И то что сейчас.

То число, которое нам нужно прибавить человеку, для его дела, заносим в бд.
Всё отлично, успешно заносится в бд. А что же первое? Что же делать с ним?
Ну себе я лично представлял что будет некое сравнение происходить, примерно вот таким образом :

```
if( $currentTime >= $toTime)
  { 
    echo "Время истекло"; 
  }else{
    $leftTime = ($toTime - $currentTime); // получим в секундах число.
  # $leftTime = 60 * ($toTime - $currentTime);// число в минутах.. и т.д.
}
```

Ну вот и получаем собственно говоря, наш таймер, который что то делает спустя целый час. Так вот, как оформить сие чудо, чтобы он брал время человека и начинал отсчёт от *к примеру регистрации  : человек зарегистрировался, получил на час получение письма, время истекло, он не подтвердил, и его удалило.*
Но тут попроще, ничего такого делать не нужно. Просто чтобы обработка как то происходила. 
 Вот пример запроса в бд.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `login` = '{$login}' and `password` = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
```

где он возвращает массив данных. Из которого, мы уже берём данные, такие как login , password , ну и date (time) . 
А дальше делать проверку? Брать значение из бд и сравнивать с текущим временем?

Тогда второй назревает вопрос. Если я даже и получил это значени и осталось минут 5 до окончания, как сделать постоянную проверку такого времени? Чтобы не при обращении была проверка, а всегда. Надеюсь всё расписал подробно и доходчиво.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого вам необходимо воспользоваться средствами cron'а, а именно настроить запуск скрипта раз в минуту\две\три (как настроите), который будет брать из базы все строки, toTime в которых меньше текущего времени и не стоит флаг "уже обработан" (в таблицу добавьте тогда еще один столбец), обрабатывать их и заносить в базу что строка обработана.

А если делать еще лучше - то создайте таблицу actions в которой будет указываться айди пользователя, название действия которое необходимо делать и срок, в который это необходимо делать. А затем уже настраиваете крон на запуск скрипта, который будет брать строки из этой таблицы где время "уже пришло", обрабатывать их (можете в зависимости от значения в столбце action написать что-то типа `switch ($resRow['action']) { case 'register': do_smth(); break }`) и после этого удалять из базы эту строчку, чтоб не держать в базе кучу лишней информации. Этот способ предпочтительнее.

Comment: Этот вариант имеет место быть. Но можно ли обойтись средствами php? Сделать проверку на каждой странице к примеру...

Comment: Это единственно верный способ. Для того чтоб какой-либо php скрипт запускался - ему непосредственно нужно чтоб кто-то его запустил - здесь и помогает крон.
Плюс php не умеет запоминать то что было при предыдущем запуске, это специфика его работы. А значит он должен либо выполняться пока не пройдет этот час, либо его нужно повторно запустить через час. Но так как крон будет запускать его каждую минуту - то вам в любом случае придется где-то хранить пришло ли время обработать того или иного пользователя - поэтому БД тоже необходима (ну или любой другой способ хранения информации, файл например)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать выполнение и на хитах.
Делаем метод, который будет обрабатывать все события для каждого пользователя:
checkEvents($userId);

Этот метод получает из таблицы все необработанные действия с их крайними сроками. Если время вышло, а задание не выполнено, то запускает нужный коллбэк для каждого события(удалить, напомнить и продлить на час и т.п.).

Если время ещё есть, можно выводить список текущих задач.

Метод checkEvents($userId) запускать при рендере страницы в начале.

Но как и говорили, лучше перенести все такие задачи на крон, который будет запускать этот же метод, только для всех пользователей.